# Extracting a vowels from an array..and storing nd printing on another array

Tags: c++, arrays

> Write a program using for loop which stores alphabets from Z-A. Extract only vowels from this array and store them into another array vowels. Now display these vowels using for loop from vowels array.

My output is not working properly. If I write my name without spaces like `abdulhananhamid`, then it works and shows `a u a a`.
I do not know how to use `cin` in a for loop, either.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

int vowel (char x);

int main()
{   
char size=100;
char x[size];
char A[5];
int n,i,;
cout<<"Enter any string\n";
cin>>x;

 for (i = 0, n = 0; i<size; i++)

    if (vowel(x[i]))
        A[n++] = x[i];

 for (n = 0;n<5;n++)
    cout << A[n] << " ";  

getch();
return 0;

 }
 int vowel(char x)   
{

 if(x=='a'||x=='e'||x=='i'||x=='o'||x=='u')
 return 1;
else
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You should change `size` to `const int size = 100;`, otherwise you are using VLAs which are not standard.

Comment: If you *must* use character arrays (instead of `std::string`), use `std::getline` for reading into the array.

Comment: There is a possibility that `A[n++]` can overflow.

Comment: You have an extra `','` in your `int` declaration.

Comment: Try this new data type, `bool`, instead of int.  Example:  `bool vowel(char x)`, so you can return `true` or `false`.  The use of 1 and 0 is so ancient technology (as in the days before C and C++ became languages).

Comment: thnx im not a proper computer science student ..i'm geology student and i know very basic c++ ...

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good assignment for using `std::string` and `std::getline`.

```
std::string user_text;
std::cout << "Enter a string: ";
while (std::getline(std::cin, user_text)
{
  const size_t length = user_text.length();
  std::string vowels;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
  {
    const char c = user_text[i];
    if ((c == 'a') || (c == 'e') || (c == 'i') || (c == 'o') || (c == 'u'))
    {
       vowels += c;
    }
  }
  std::cout << "Vowels found: " << vowels << "\n";
  std::cout << "\nEnter a string: ";
}
```

If you must use character arrays, you should check for overflow:

```
unsigned int MAXIMUM_CHARACTERS = 128;
char user_text[MAXIMUM_CHARACTERS];
char vowels_found[MAXIMUM_CHARACTERS];
std::cout << "Enter a string: ";
while (std::cin.getline(&user_text[0], MAXIMUM_CHARACTERS))
{
  unsigned int vowel_index = 0U;
  const size_t length = strlen(user_text);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
  {
    const char c = user_text[i];
    if ((c == 'a') || (c == 'e') || (c == 'i') || (c == 'o') || (c == 'u'))
    {
       vowels_found[vowel_index++] = c;
    }
  }
  vowels_found[vowel_index] = '\0';
  std::cout << "Vowels found: " << vowels_found << "\n";
  std::cout << "\nEnter a string: ";
}
```

A function for checking for a vowel could look like:

```
bool is_vowel(char c)
{
  return (c == 'a') || (c == 'e') || (c == 'i') || (c == 'o') || (c == 'u');
}
```

Comment: your logic totally not make sense to me..i don't know built in functions that much...but i try.thnx..:P